# How to add pagination to a table with dynamic data source?

Tags: knockout.js, oracle-jet

I want to dynamically fetch data, when the particular page is clicked in the pagination bar at the bottom.
How to add pagination to a table with dynamic data source?
The pagination works with dataSource which is predefined number of data, but I want to fetch the data dynamically based on the page number.

Comment: How is this related to Knockoutjs?

Comment: ojet is based on knockout js only.